# MySQL reading from csv file inserts values in weird way

Tags: mysql, csv

so I have a .csv file which only contains one line like so:

```
"Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1","Resto1"
```

This is the SQL statement I execute to read into the table I created:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/me/Desktop/mydir/data.csv'
INTO TABLE tester2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

and this is the structure of the table after executing 'describe tester2'

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
r1  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r2  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r3  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r4  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r5  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r6  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r7  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r8  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r9  varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r10 varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r11 varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r12 varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r13 varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r14 varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r15 varchar(30) YES     NULL    
r16 varchar(30) YES     NULL
```

When I run this, it executes okay with no errors. Since the csv line only has 14 "Resto 1" values, it inserts up until r14, leaving r15 and r16 null. This is all fine, but I realized that after querying

```
select * from tester2
```

r14 is presented different. This is how the query result looks:

```
r10     r11     r12     r13      r14     r15     r16
Resto1  Resto1  Resto1  Resto1  "Resto1"  NULL   NULL
```

So my question is, why does the last Resto1 in column r14 get stored with the double quotes and the other ones don't? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to add OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

Answer (score 0):

By removing the ENCLOSED BY '"' statement, I resolved my problem. Still don't know why that worked though. Thanks everyone nonetheless.